# jquery carousel slider fade in/center images

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel

Was wondering if anyone could help my revise the script on this site so that the images fade in slightly slower on initial load and also how to center the images when the left/right arrows are clicked.
Right now they justify left.

Site here:

http://oddopolis.com/2012/index.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ups you don't have  somme kind of options like that.
I'd just look at the code of this plugin you use and the time is hard-coded.

maybe you can do a little custom by extending the easing :

```
$.extend(jQuery.easing, {
easeInOutSine : function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    return -c / 2 * (Math.cos(Math.PI * t / d) - 1) + b
},
easeOutSine : function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    return c * Math.sin(t / d * (Math.PI / 2)) + b
},
easeOutCubic : function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    return c * ((t = t / d - 1) * t * t + 1) + b
}
})
```